# Dose exists a good tools to make a design and get in the end an Xml file

Tags: android

I am using a mac and Searching a good tools to make a design example nice Button and in the end that going to generate a xml file?, i already know "DroidDraw" i am searching something more comply .

Thanks for Helping

Comment: you can use the AppInventor by connecting device..

Comment: Ok but i can't get an xml file to implement in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to generate just the UI?  I'm assuming you have tried the WYSIWYG editor already packaged/bundled with ADT plugins for Eclipse right?  You can get a UI editor with it.  Open up the layout.xml file and click on the graphical tab.  If you don't have ADT grab it here:  http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html.  It has a visual editor that is (IMO) good for a lot of things http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html.

If you have that already and are looking for alternatives, try some of these:

1. http://code.google.com/p/android-ui-utils/ Android-ui-utils.  Interesting and easy, for graphics take a look at the asset studio.
2. http://speckyboy.com/2010/05/10/android-app-developers-gui-kits-icons-fonts-and-tools/?mobify=0  There's a list of tools at this site.

My strong suggestion is to stick to the graphical builder that comes with ADT and integrates directly into Eclipse (the first links above) if you need a graphical editor.